# How a processor scales in terms of components

Tags: cpu

I'm still very early in understanding some computer science basics. I find it easiest to learn things when I have some oversight of what I can expect. Is there any trend to the number of logical gates that processors have, from 1-bit to 2-bit, 4-bit, 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit. This processor, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/74181, is a 4-bit and has 75 logic gates. Can expected number for 8-bits be calculated mathematically, is there a rough trend for how many more gates can be expected? Does not have to be exact at all, just very rough trend. Do they increase with the square, cube, or just double (likely not that...), or whatever mathematical function might give some rough approximation.

Comment: (The SN74181 hasn't been a processor, but a four-bit building block for an ALU. And with more complicated structures such as flip-flops, counting *gate*s is somewhat difficult as well as besides the point and has not been prominent as a measure of complexity - I seem to remember #transistors. With the number of components growing, interconnect becomes more of a concern. With CPUs, I think transistors in caches&alike should be tallied separately. Not sure about largish multi-ported *implemented* *register file*s (as opposed to architectural register sets).)

Comment: (And while extending to 8 bits by using two '181s is easy to compute, note the mention of the '182 "carry handling circuit". Late in the game there was an 8-bit variant - '881? Eyeball the schematics: The one thing getting more complicated as the bit index increases is the carry handling. An abundance of papers has been published about the complexity of different implementations for addition and multiplication, not quite as many on division, square-rooting, transcendental functions.)

Comment: @greybeard I just need something to go by to start with. Transistor count might work too, but, logical gates give me more of an idea of what calculations and computations each processor does, and how that scales with n-bit ALU. But I guess one can be estimated from the other. I am assuming most transistors in a processor is in the ALU, seems like it from what I learnt so far, but, would be good to have a rough idea of how much is ALU and how much is the rest of it.

Comment: I'm not looking for exact and high resolution detail, just, a very rough and zoomed out oversight of what has been happening as processors have doubled in bitsize. If there is a trend. Like, Gordon Moore discovered the trend of transistor count doubling every 2 years.

Comment: Z80 was 8-bit and has 8500 transistors, that might be equivalent to a few thousand logical gates? What would be transistor count for a comparable 4-bit processor, historically? And then 16-bit? And maybe 2-bit if those were ever a thing. From that, must be some type of mathematical trend that can be seen. re: flip flops, flip flops, are new to me, I have covered a lot of basic microprocessor stuff so far but have not gotten around to flip flops yet. I get adders, all logical gates, transistors, bus, registry, controller, ALU, etc. Will be learning flip flops in the next few days most likely.